# Creating Entry widgets with for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, widget

As a proof of concept this creates Entry widgets and places them in an array. The problem is I only get 24 instead of 26 Entry widgets with 3.3.1 on Windows and 28 with 3.3.1 on Lubuntu. Why? and how do I fix this?

**EDIT2:** Simplified the code to just the problematic part https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubU6b.png:
http://pastebin.com/2791MFRu

```
from tkinter import *

class test:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.variables = []
        for i in range(26):
            self.variables.append(StringVar())

        self.frames = []
        self.labels = []
        self.entrys = []
        for i in range(2):
            self.frames.append(Frame(root))
            for ii in range(26):
                char = str(chr(ord('A') + ii))
                if i == 0:
                    self.labels.append(Label(self.frames[0] , text = char))
                    self.labels[-1].grid(padx=0, pady=0, row=ii, column=i)
                else:
                    self.entrys.append(Entry(self.frames[1], textvariable =self.variables[ii]))
                    self.entrys[-1].grid(padx=0, pady=0, row=ii, column=i)
            self.frames[i].grid(row = 0,column=i)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x600+50+50")
T = test(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you give us the whole code, so that we can try it out ourselves?

Comment: Your indentation seems incorrect.

Comment: When I run the above code I get 26 entry widgets. Why do you think you're getting fewer than 26?

Comment: Done, it's correct, see screenshot

Comment: It only appears that there are two missing entries, since there aren't any directly next to the first and last label. Perhaps the correct question is, "why aren't my 26 labels lining up with my 26 text boxes?" Notice how the H label is halfway between two entries.

Comment: I know that this is an old question, but for future reference, you should include the code in the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 26 entries, but since each one is shorter than its corresponding label, they are packed together tighter and go out of phase.

[image]

This occurs because you are putting the two columns in their own frames, and each frame aligns items as tightly as possible within their own grid, ignoring the other column.

You can get proper alignment by removing the column frames entirely, and putting the labels and entries directly in the root:

```
from tkinter import *

class test:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.variables = []
        for i in range(26):
            self.variables.append(StringVar())

        self.labels = []
        self.entrys = []
        for ii in range(26):
            char = str(chr(ord('A') + ii))
            self.labels.append(Label(root , text = char))
            self.labels[-1].grid(padx=0, pady=0, row=ii, column=0)
            self.entrys.append(Entry(root, textvariable =self.variables[ii]))
            self.entrys[-1].grid(padx=0, pady=0, row=ii, column=1)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x600+50+50")
T = test(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]